# Docker images and modules

Tags: python, image, docker, terminal, module

Let's assume that we have created a container from an image, for example, Node-Red. There are several images of Node-Red with or without modules, like python, pandas and other modules:

With Python (default)

```
docker run -it -p 1880:1880 -v node_red_data:/data --name mynodered nodered/node-red:latest
```

Without Python

```
docker run -it -p 1880:1880 -v node_red_data:/data --name mynodered nodered/node-red:latest-minimal
```

If we do not remember which one we installed how can we ensure what we installed?

1. Can we ensure that our container has been built with a specific image (none or latest) with the following commands?

   sudo docker container ls
2. Can we ensure that our container has the python inside with the following commands?

   docker exec -it  bash

   cd node_modules

   ls
3. Can we install pandas or any other module inside a container installed via image without having pandas?

   docker exec -it  bash

   "install my module"

My problem is that I have installed Node-Red as a container with python and python3. Some nodes require pandas and sklearn modules. Unfortunately, these modules are not contained in Node-Red image and I am looking for a way to install them inside the container.

[image]

Once I attach the bash on the container with root user, I can execute the following command:

```
pip install pandas
```

But I get a huge error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-nfst1lxs/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (703 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.17.3
    Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-jvnvy0mv
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/
    Complete output (331 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    blis_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    openblas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /bin/sh: svnversion: not found
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    openblas_lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    openblas_clapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    flame_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'intel', 'lahey', 'pg', 'absoft', 'nag', 'vast', 'compaq', 'intele', 'intelem', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pathf95', 'nagfor']'
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize IntelFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifc
    customize LaheyFCompiler
    Could not locate executable lf95
    customize PGroupFCompiler
    Could not locate executable pgfortran
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize NAGFCompiler
    customize VastFCompiler
    customize CompaqFCompiler
    Could not locate executable fort
    customize IntelItaniumFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize PathScaleFCompiler
    Could not locate executable pathf95
    customize NAGFORCompiler
    Could not locate executable nagfor
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
    C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC
  
    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c'
    gcc: _configtest.c
    gcc _configtest.o -o _configtest
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d _configtest
    C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC
  
    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c'
    gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'exp'; expected 'double(double)' [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
        1 | int exp (void);
          |     ^~~
    _configtest.c:1:1: note: 'exp' is declared in header '<math.h>'
      +++ |+#include <math.h>
        1 | int exp (void);
    gcc _configtest.o -o _configtest
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d _configtest
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
      adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
    building library "npysort" sources
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h
      adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/timsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
    building extension "numpy.core._dummy" sources
    Generating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h
    C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC
  
    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c'
    gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
        1 | #include <Python.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/setup.py", line 443, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 142, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
        self.build_extension_sources(ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 316, in build_extension_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 369, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 430, in generate_config_h
        moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 49, in check_types
        out = check_types(*a, **kw)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 286, in check_types
        raise SystemError(
    SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
    Running setup.py clean for numpy
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy
    Complete output (10 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
  
    `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
  
      - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
      - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                          files that aren't checked into the git repo)
  
    Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
  
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-lu_pr29g/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-nfst1lxs/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-nfst1lxs/overlay/include/python3.8/numpy
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/
      Complete output (322 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
  
      Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
      with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
  
        - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                 release)
        - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
  
  
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      blis_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /tmp/pip-install-ldkko_7q/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /bin/sh: svnversion: not found
      non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_lapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_clapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      flame_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
```

---

more error but cannot fill here

Comment: Since the data is stored in a named volume outside the container, it should be safe to stop and delete the existing container and launch a new container that you're sure is running the right image.

Comment: @David Maze, That's true, but what if we need in the future to install again and again modules that are not in the image? We need to know the way. By the way, I figured out that I have the right image of Node-Red with python, but not pandas, and there is no image for that. This makes machine learning nodes usable if I cannot install pandas inside the container.

Comment: Build a custom image that installs your software.  You can double-check that the Dockerfile's `FROM` line contains the right base image.  You shouldn't usually install software inside running containers precisely because it will be lost when the container is deleted, and it's very routine to delete containers (to change startup-time options, to upgrade the software in the image, to take a security fix).

Comment: how i can build the docker file? can you provide some instructions on the FROM? Should i place FROM nodered/node-red?

Comment: I just tried to build a new dockerfile with FROM nodered/node-red and install pandas as a requirement and i get the same message.